# SQL - WHERE query with a mix of XOR and AND on two variables

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I have two column names `foo` and `bar` from a table. I want to return any row that returns true on the conditions put on `X` and `Y`. I want to combine the conditions in the table below into the `where` section of my `select` query.

```
   X      |    Y     |  conditions
----------+----------+----------------
   null   |   null   | 
 not null |   null   |  foo=X
   null   | not null |  bar=Y
 not null | not null |  foo=X and bar=Y
```

Here `X` and `Y` are variables that get substituted into the query. Both of them are never null at the same time, so we don't care about the first condition. But if one is null the condition checks the other (XOR). If both are not null the condition checks on both (AND).
This is the query I have so far, but is there anything simpler and cleaner for the `where` portion?

```
select
      ...
where
     (X is not null and Y is not null and
      foo=X and bar=Y)
  or (X is not null and
      Y is null and foo=X)
  or (X is null and
      Y is not null and bar=Y)
```

**EDIT** Note: `foo` and `bar` may have null values.

Comment: do you want to show both null variables too ?

Comment: @OnlyMAJ that should never be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the condition by observing that the pair `X, foo` is independent of the pair `Y, bar`. Therefore, you can simplify the condition as follows:

```
WHERE (X is NULL OR foo=X) AND (Y is NULL OR bar=Y)
```

Comment: They unfortunately can be nullable.

Comment: @Julio I edited the answer to simplify the condition a little. This will work with nullable columns, too.